# Is my browser sending any information about my linux distribution?

Tags: linux

I understand that the server can find out my IP address, location, browser information and OS. About the OS... If I am running Linux, is it possible for the server to find out what Linux distribution am I using?

Comment: It totally depends on the website if they want to collect that information or not

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Nope, if it is not some hackers website and it gets only the information that the browser sends it, there are limited things that it can find out. The question is specifically about linux distro.

Comment: Assuming only hackers can find out that would be incorrect. For User Experience testing, marketing, research etc purposes a lot of data is collected by various websites. Finding out what Linux distro you are running, if a website wants to know should not be difficult at this age

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most probably.  Click this [link](https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes) to see what your browser sends to the web server.  The OS should be listed under the first category called "User Agent"

Comment: I have been to this website, but there is nothing about OS information

Comment: are you sure?  what does the user agent report?

Comment: Wll, it reports it as Linux 64 bit...  not the distro...

Comment: Yes, and the question was specifically about the distribution. If a website can get the information about my distro

Comment: if you run browser extensions, those can report info as well

Comment: you title says otherwise

Comment: You want to say the browser extensions can report my distribution?

Comment: For me the given link reports also my distribution, so I guess it may vary, depending on browser and (maybe) distro. You see only what is being reported.

Comment: What info do you get about your OS?

Comment: @Alex My whole "User Agent" field is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0` if it helps.

Comment: Ok, but why don't I get any info? Am I secured without knowing that? :D

Comment: Probably because your browser doesn't report your distribution, or isn't able to recognize the one you are using. However, I am just guessing ;)

Comment: @Adalee: Looks like Firefox reports your distro (amusingly, it gets mine wrong, claiming that my Linux Mint install is Ubuntu rather than one of the many Ubuntu downstreams). Chrome doesn't. Don't like that FF does that, but then, I suppose Windows browsers have been specifying the precise Windows version for a long time...

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and there are a few things listed in System Fonts that give it away: `Ubuntu, Ubuntu Condensed, Ubuntu Mono`. Of course that is not conclusive, but you can collect some information and piece it together.

Answer (score 2):

Another good site that will show you what a website can learn about your system when visiting the site is [BrowserSpy.dk](http://browserspy.dk/); the [Electronic Frontier Foundation (EFF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Frontier_Foundation) site listed in Keltari's answer uses some of the code from BrowserSpy.dk. If you click on [Browser](http://browserspy.dk/browser.php) on the menu on the left of the home page, you will see information regarding your browser. When I visit the page using Firefox on a Ubuntu Linux system, I see "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:24.0) Gecko/201001 Firefox/24.0)"

Answer (score 0):

There are several places browser may send info:

- `User-Agent` HTTP header. It is a part of HTTP specification and each request has one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent  .As you can see, there is rendering engine name , browser version and OS name. Use "developer toolbar" or "firebug" to find list of headers your browser sends: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome
- JavaScript: there is `Navigator` class in JavaScript, it provides os name and browser name: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp . Some sites may use JS to detect this info and send it back to server. You may use simple JS  to check `alert(navigator.appName); alert(navigator.platform);`
- TCP/IP stack fingerprinting: different TCP/IP implementations (WinSock vs Berkley sockets) and different OS versions have slightly different default options. Some heuristic could be used to detect OS family. This is hacker-style approach and used very rarely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting
- Modern JavaScript can also report your position (like GPS) via Geolocation API, but it always asks you if you want to provide this info to Server or not: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

By the way, it is not always possible for server to find your real IP. In case of proxy, proxy *may* send your real IP to server (using `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` headers), but it does not have to.
And you may even have no public IP if NAT is configured on your router. In this case server will only know your router's public IP and there could the whole office (several hundred people) under one pulic IP.

Answer (score 0):

Your user-agent string is usually sent to the website you are visiting. This UA string is then deciphered and will usually be enough to identify some very basic info about your machine.

Using Chrome, this is how my web browser introduces itself to this site:

[image]